# Drupal: How to get deeplink to comment?

Tags: optimization, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I need to build and print a deeplink to any given comment. So that the user can directly access the specific comment with just clicking a link. I could not find a native drupal function to get this so i build it my own.

### My solution

```
<?php
    global $base_url;
    $base = drupal_lookup_path('alias',"node/".$node->nid);
    $path = $base_url.'/'.$base.'#comment-'.$comment->cid;

    $link_options = array('html'=> $html);
    $commentlink = l($date, $path, $link_options);
?>
```

To print the link you only have to call `<?php print $commentlink;?>`. But i'm pretty sure there is better and much more drupal like way to solve the problem.

### The Better Way

Mikeker did it :) As he suggested here are the solution.

```
<?php
 $commentlink = l(
    $date,
    "node/$comment->nid",
    array("fragment" => "comment-$comment->cid"));
?>
```

Note the little difference bettween Mikeker and my version. `array("fragment" => "comment-$comment->cid"));` and `array("query" => "comment-$comment->cid"));`

The query param will add an `?` to the url. So your path looks like

```
//…query
http://example.com/path/to/node?comment-2
```

In opposite to my solution (fragment):

```
//…fragment
http://example.com/path/to/node#comment-2
```

**Note:**
Do not include the leading '#' character to a fragment identifier. It will be added by drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basically the way to do it.  Comment permalinks are in the form of:

```
node/<nid>#comment-<cid>
```

Where `<nid>` and `<cid>` are the node and comment IDs, respectively.  You can save yourself a step by not doing calling `drupal_lookup_path()` -- `l()` or `url()` do it for you.  The shortened routine would look like:

```
$commentlink = l(
  $date,                                      // Text of the link
  "node/$node->nid",                          // path to node, l() handles aliases
  array('query' => "comment/$comment->cid"),  // fragment to specific comment
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was wondering, the Drupal 7 way (at least, appears to be) this:

```
<a href='http://YOURSITE.com/comment/CID#comment-CID'>link text</a>
```

For example:

```
print "<a href='/comment/$comment->cid#comment-$comment->cid'>text here</a>";
```

And this would be placed in, perhaps, a comment.tpl.php file.